# How can I solve can only concatenate str (not "int") to str when finding mean value?

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing a project as a python and machine learning beginner and came across Titanic dataset. I wanted to fill the NaN (fillna) value with mean for continuous data. But when I did this:

```
df['Age']=df['Age'].fillna(df['Age'].mean())
df['Age'].isnull().sum()
```

It always gives me

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str.
```

Both data types are object and I have tried to change the data type but it is useless. How can I solve this?

Comment: You need to change the dtype of `Age` column first. Please check `df['Age'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Age'], errors='coerce')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert your column to int type, using `to_numeric()`.

```
df["Age"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Age"])
```